# How to consume a wsdl file that doesn't exist on web in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to impliment a service with SOAP messages to my visual studio project.
They gave me some instructions and I saw on stackoverflow that I have to consume the wsdl and xsd file in visual studio so that it can create all the classes that I need.
The problem is that when I try to add the wsdl file as service reference it says that the file doesnt exist. I search it myself using the URL provided and it really doesnt exists.
Is there any way so that I can use it.

```
Below is the WSDL statement:
https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws?wsdl
<definitions targetNamespace="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl" name="rmt_ws"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl"
schemaLocation="https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="remittanceXml">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:remittanceXml"/>
</message>
<message name="remittanceXmlResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:remittanceXmlResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="UnsupportedEncodingException">
<part name="fault" element="tns:UnsupportedEncodingException"/>
</message>
<portType name="rmt_ws">
<operation name="remittanceXml">
<input message="tns:remittanceXml"/>
<output message="tns:remittanceXmlResponse"/>
<fault message="tns:UnsupportedEncodingException" name="UnsupportedEncodingException"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="rmt_wsBinding" type="tns:rmt_ws">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="remittanceXml">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
<fault name="UnsupportedEncodingException">
<soap:fault name="UnsupportedEncodingException" use="literal"/>
</fault>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="rmt_ws">
<port name="rmt_ws" binding="tns:rmt_wsBinding">
<soap:address location="https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

and here is the xsd

```
 https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws?xsd=1
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl"
xmlns:tns="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="UnsupportedEncodingException" type="tns:UnsupportedEncodingException"/>
<xs:element name="remittanceXml" type="tns:remittanceXml"/>
<xs:element name="remittanceXmlResponse" type="tns:remittanceXmlResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="remittanceXml">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="inputXML" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="remittanceXmlResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="UnsupportedEncodingException">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
Δείγμα μηνύματος:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:rmt="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<rmt:remittanceXml>
<inputXML>&lt;remittance&gt;&lt;wsTin&gt;Tin&lt;/wsTin&gt;&lt;wsUser&gt;Username&lt;/wsUser&gt;&lt;wsPswd
&gt;Pswd&lt;/wsPswd&gt;&lt;contain&gt;&lt;bmrn&gt;16GRIMXXXX00001746&lt;/bmrn&gt;&lt;blrn&gt;TESTFOR1&
lt;/blrn&gt;&lt;bcnt&gt;1&lt;/bcnt&gt;&lt;bafm&gt;099099099&lt;/bafm&gt;&lt;/contain&gt;&lt;contain&gt;&lt;bmr
n&gt;16GRIMXXXX00001720&lt;/bmrn&gt;&lt;blrn&gt;TESTFOR2&lt;/blrn&gt;&lt;bcnt&gt;2&lt;/bcnt&gt;&lt;bafm&
gt;099099099&lt;/bafm&gt;&lt;/contain&gt;&lt;contain&gt;&lt;bmrn&gt;16GRIMXXXX00001738&lt;/bmrn&gt;&lt;bl
rn&gt;TESTFOR2&lt;/blrn&gt;&lt;bcnt&gt;2&lt;/bcnt&gt;&lt;bafm&gt;099099099&lt;/bafm&gt;&lt;/contain&gt;&lt;/
remittance&gt;</inputXML>
</rmt:remittanceXml>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Those are in a pdf file that they gave me.

EDIT:
If I add it as a file from service references it creates the reference ePayments and no .cs file.
When I add the reference it gives me only one service rmt_ws which has an operation remitanceXML and nothing else.
I don't know if this is correct and how should I use it

Comment: You could create a webservice reference in visual studio also from a local file, but it must have the same format as received from the web. I think it should be possible to create a wsdl file from the text in pdf, but it not very easy and needs some trial and error.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen I forgot to say that I tried that. I explain what happens when I try to add it from local file in my last edit

Comment: When I add it as file in service reference and click it to view it in object browser it doesn't exist and so I can't use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember, that I had a problem with authentication of a web service some years ago, but I didn't remember where I found this alternative solution:

- Create a new console app in visual studio (I am not sure, if deleting the old service reference in the existing project works without manual editing project file etc.)
- Select add service reference as before, but don't enter the path of a wsdl. Instead press the button "Advanced..." in the dialog and "Add Web reference..." in the next dialog.
- In the new dialog enter the path of the wsdl file and press "Add reference"
- Open the file "program.cs" in the project and add this class with namespace between the last "using..." line and "namespace...."

  ```
  namespace TestWeb.WebReference 
  {
  partial class rmt_ws : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {
      protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri) 
      {
          System.Net.HttpWebRequest request;

          request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);

          if (PreAuthenticate) {
              System.Net.NetworkCredential networkCredentials = Credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
              if (networkCredentials != null) {
                  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("User: " + networkCredentials.UserName);
                  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PW: " + networkCredentials.Password);
                  byte[] credentialBuffer = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(networkCredentials.UserName + ":" + networkCredentials.Password);
                  request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(credentialBuffer);
              }
              else {
                  throw new ApplicationException("No network credentials");
              }
          }
          return request;
      }
  }
  ```
- Replace "TestWeb" (first line of inserted code) with the namespace of your project (normally the project name).
- Replace the existing class "Program" with the following code:

  ```
  class Program {
      static void Main(string[] args) {
          // Fill with a valid xml request
          String inputXML = "";
          String answer = "";
          try {
              WebReference.rmt_ws _webService = new WebReference.rmt_ws();
              System.Net.CredentialCache myCredentials = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
              // Set correct user and password
              System.Net.NetworkCredential netCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("User", "Password");
              _webService.Credentials = netCred.GetCredential(new Uri(_webService.Url), "Basic");
              _webService.PreAuthenticate = true;
              answer = _webService.remittanceXml(inputXML);
          }
          catch (Exception ex) {
              Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
          }
          Console.WriteLine(answer);
          Console.ReadLine();
      }
  }
  ```
- Set inputXML with a valid xml for your request
- Set the correct user and password

If this does not help you should really open a new question to find some one other who could help.

Comment: Great that worked. My problem was that for some reason it didn't send the credentials in header. With this code everything is working fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: I am happy that I could help. If this answer works for you, please confirm it (Click the arrow "This answer is useful")

Answer (score 3):

I copied the xsd part into the wsdl and visual studio generates a service with one operation to send an input XML and return another XML. I hope, this helps.

rmt_ws.wsdl:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl" name="rmt_ws" targetNamespace="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
        <types>
            <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="UnsupportedEncodingException" type="tns:UnsupportedEncodingException" />
      <xs:element name="remittanceXml" type="tns:remittanceXml" />
      <xs:element name="remittanceXmlResponse" type="tns:remittanceXmlResponse" />
      <xs:complexType name="remittanceXml">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="inputXML" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="remittanceXmlResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="UnsupportedEncodingException">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="remittanceXml">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:remittanceXml" />
  </message>
  <message name="remittanceXmlResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:remittanceXmlResponse" />
  </message>
  <message name="UnsupportedEncodingException">
    <part name="fault" element="tns:UnsupportedEncodingException" />
  </message>
  <portType name="rmt_ws">
    <operation name="remittanceXml">
      <input message="tns:remittanceXml" />
      <output message="tns:remittanceXmlResponse" />
      <fault name="UnsupportedEncodingException" message="tns:UnsupportedEncodingException" />
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="rmt_wsBinding" type="tns:rmt_ws">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="remittanceXml">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </output>
      <fault name="UnsupportedEncodingException">
        <soap:fault use="literal" name="UnsupportedEncodingException" namespace="" />
      </fault>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="rmt_ws">
    <port name="rmt_ws" binding="tns:rmt_wsBinding">
      <soap:address location="https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws" />
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Can you help me on how should I use this on my project? Should I add it as reference , should I create a new .cs file? IThis is my first time that I use wsdl files and soap messages so my knowledge is poor.

Comment: In visual studio project right-click references and select "Add service reference". In the dialog enter your wsdl file with full path and click "Go". The interface of the service should be displayed in the box below. Enter a namespace (default ServiceRreference1) an press ok. The service reference is shown in "Connected services" in the project tree and you could view it in object browser.

Comment: Should I use your wsdl file because when I did that with the wsdl file they provide me when I add it in service reference it doesn't show in object browser even when I compile it

Comment: Yes, you should use the file I created. The original one uses an import statement `<xsd:import namespace="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl"
schemaLocation="https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws?xsd=1"/>`. I only replaced this statement with the xsd from your post because import from https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws?xsd=1 will not work.

Comment: It gives me an error when I try to import it.The document at the url payments.wsdl was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be <schema> and its namespace should be 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Discovery document at the URL wdsl/epayments.wsdl could not be found.'.

Comment: - The document format is not recognized.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (55, 13).'.
  - Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: definitions. Line 55, position 13.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Comment: I add </definitions> in the end of file and I manage to import it bit altough it add it to Service reference I cannot see it in object browser and I cannot call it using the namsepace I used even if I rebuild the project

Comment: Sorry I rebuild all solution and now I can see it in object browser. Can you help me on how to use this classes. Do I have to initialize it? How it will return me the values?

Comment: Yes, you have to initialize the service class (something like  `var myService = rmt_wsClient(....)` and then you could call the method `String result = myService.remittanceXml(inputXML);` But you have to initialize it with the correct url as described in this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2013/10/28/wcf-programming-how-to-write-a-client-app-that-connects-to-a-wcf-service/ Visual Studio handles a webservice as a special kind of WCF service.

Comment: I manage to initialize and edit the appropriate files (app.config) in my project but can  you tell me how can I check if my inputXML is send in the correct url (https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws) IS there a state that I can check if it connects to the page. And I couldn't find how can I take the result string. I use this code 'remittanceXmlResponse response = new remittanceXmlResponse(request.inputXML);
                    var result = response.@return;' But I don't get a response, I only get the same as request.inputXML

Comment: Try this: `ServiceReference1.rmt_ws client = new ServiceReference1.rmt_wsClient(); ServiceReference1.remittanceXmlResponse result = client.remittanceXml(new ServiceReference1.remittanceXmlRequest(inputXML)); String response = result.@return;` But it will throw an exception. I think you will need some kind of authentication. That is depending of the service. Btw: This has nothing to do with your original question. If you have problems to connent the service maybe it is better to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I contact again for the communication problem and they send me this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<con:soapui-project id="6026c0c2-d6a6-487f-8551-c5f616d5efab" xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config" runType="SEQUENTIAL" abortOnError="false" soapui-version="5.2.1" resourceRoot="" name="pre-prod" activeEnvironment="Default">
<con:settings/>
<con:interface id="dba85261-52fb-48a6-96c0-9fcedc1e8146" name="rmt_wsBinding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" definition="https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws?wsdl" anonymous="optional" soapVersion="1_1" bindingName="{http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl}rmt_wsBinding" type="wsdl" xsi:type="con:WsdlInterface" wsaVersion="NONE">
<con:settings/>
<con:definitionCache type="TEXT" rootPart="https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws?wsdl">
<con:part>
<con:url>https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws?wsdl</con:url>
<con:content>
<![CDATA[
<!--Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5.-->
<!--Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5.-->
<definitions targetNamespace="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl" name="rmt_ws" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl" schemaLocation="https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws?xsd=1"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="remittanceXml">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:remittanceXml"/>
  </message>
  <message name="remittanceXmlResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:remittanceXmlResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="UnsupportedEncodingException">
    <part name="fault" element="tns:UnsupportedEncodingException"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="rmt_ws">
    <operation name="remittanceXml">
      <input message="tns:remittanceXml"/>
      <output message="tns:remittanceXmlResponse"/>
      <fault message="tns:UnsupportedEncodingException" name="UnsupportedEncodingException"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="rmt_wsBinding" type="tns:rmt_ws">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="remittanceXml">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
      <fault name="UnsupportedEncodingException">
        <soap:fault name="UnsupportedEncodingException" use="literal"/>
      </fault>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="rmt_ws">
    <port name="rmt_ws" binding="tns:rmt_wsBinding">
      <soap:address location="https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
]]>
</con:content>
<con:type>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/</con:type>
</con:part>
<con:part>
<con:url>https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws?xsd=1</con:url>
<con:content>
<![CDATA[
<!--Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5.-->
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl" xmlns:tns="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="UnsupportedEncodingException" type="tns:UnsupportedEncodingException"/>
  <xs:element name="remittanceXml" type="tns:remittanceXml"/>
  <xs:element name="remittanceXmlResponse" type="tns:remittanceXmlResponse"/>
  <xs:complexType name="remittanceXml">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="inputXML" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="remittanceXmlResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="UnsupportedEncodingException">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
]]>
</con:content>
<con:type>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</con:type>
</con:part>
</con:definitionCache>
<con:endpoints>
<con:endpoint>https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws</con:endpoint>
</con:endpoints>
<con:operation id="432ec623-b52f-49b6-bff5-ff220d2dc4e8" name="remittanceXml" anonymous="optional" type="Request-Response" sendsAttachments="false" receivesAttachments="false" inputName="" bindingOperationName="remittanceXml" action="" isOneWay="false">
<con:settings/>
<con:call id="84ad3fc8-b5a2-491b-b375-8fc6d8b5edb4" name="Request 1">
<con:settings>
<con:setting id="com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlRequest@request-headers"><xml-fragment/></con:setting>
</con:settings>
<con:encoding>UTF-8</con:encoding>
<con:endpoint>https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicispay/rmt_ws</con:endpoint>
<con:request>
<![CDATA[]]>
</con:request>
<con:credentials>
<con:USERNAME>USERNAME</con:USERNAME>
<con:PASSWORD>PASSWORD</con:PASSWORD>
<con:username>USERNAME</con:username>
<con:password>PASSWORD</con:password>
<con:selectedAuthProfile>Basic</con:selectedAuthProfile>
<con:addedBasicAuthenticationTypes>Basic</con:addedBasicAuthenticationTypes>
<con:authType>Global HTTP Settings</con:authType>
</con:credentials>
<con:jmsConfig JMSDeliveryMode="PERSISTENT"/>
<con:jmsPropertyConfig/>
<con:wsaConfig action="http://remittance_ws/rmt_ws.wsdl/rmt_ws/remittanceXmlRequest" version="200508" mustUnderstand="NONE"/>
<con:wsrmConfig version="1.2"/>
</con:call>
</con:operation>
</con:interface>
<con:properties/>
<con:wssContainer/>
<con:oAuth2ProfileContainer/>
</con:soapui-project>
```

Can I use this file in visual studio ? Is this better for the previous?

Comment: I don't think you can use this file in Visual Studio. It seems to be a project file of SoapUI, a web service testing tool (see: https://www.soapui.org/). What kind of problems you have now? Did you try the code from my last comment? What was the result (Exception, Error message, etc)? If you get something like "authentication error" or "authentication failed" the connection works principially and you should open a new question in stackoverflow to ask for help with this authentication error.

Comment: It throws an exception that I have to declare authenication in ClientCredentials. but this is in rmt_wsClient. If I change rmt_ws client = new rmt_wsClient() with rmt_wsClient client = new rmt_wsClient(); I have error in inputxml that it cannot convert from remittanceXmlRequest to string

Comment: if you use rmt_wsClient instead of the interface, you don't need to create an request object. Instead call the method with the inputXML string directly: `answer = client.remittanceXml(inputXML);`

Comment: I tried that already but I always get an error Cannot implicity convert type 'string' to remittanceXmlResponse . I tried with inputXML.tostring() as well

Comment: Sorry, my fault. In this case also the answer is a string. The same as `remittanceXmlResponse result = rmt.remittanceXml(...); String answer = result.@return`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will open a new question to solve the authentication problem.